# Передача данных из checkbox в Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Задача передать через POST объекты класса Service, отмеченные галочкой в checkbox. Как это сделать никак не пойму.

Код html:

```
<form action="/calc" type="post">
  <div th:each="e : ${service}">
    <input th:attr="id=@{'service-'} + ${e.service_id}" name="service" type="checkbox" />
    <label th:attr="for=@{'service-'} + ${e.service_id}" th:text="${e.name}" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form
```

Контроллер:

```
@GetMapping("/calc")
    public String calc(Model model) {
    Iterable<Service> service = serviceRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("service", service);
    return "calc";
}
```

Класс Service

```
@Entity
public class Service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long service_id;

    private String name;
    private double price;

    // конструкторы, гетеры и сеттеры опускаю
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

надо передать в модель обьект  у которого будет поле с выделенными обьектами, назвать класс типа markeredServices с полем `Iterable<Sevice> services`
Тоесть

```
 <form action="/calc" type="post"  th:object="${ВАШ ОБЬЕКТ С ПОЛЕМ   Iterable где будут хранится выделенные обьекты Service}">    <div th:each="e : ${service}"> 
    <input th:field="*{Тут поле обьекта где будет хранится колекция}" type="checkbox" th:value="${e.id}"/> ...
```

Ну и ловить его в контроллере с post мапингом и нужно создать спринг конвертор который будет конвертировать id Обьекта сервис в полноценный обьект Тоесть
ВАШ КЛАСС implements Converter<long, Service>
Не знаю насколько это правильный вариант, может есть в разы проще, но должно работать. Мне лень все расписывать, если не понятно, то откройте книгу Spring in Action и там во второй главе как раз написан способ передачи обьектов, именно то про что вы спрашиваете

Comment: Спасибо, помог разобраться

Comment: @Алексей чтоб отблагодарить выбери мой ответ правильным,  мне репу поднимут